# How to make this discriminated union work?

Tags: typescript

Trying to create a simple table component, but having a bit of trouble with making the typings work as I want.

TL;DR How do write the type for `Column3` in this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=39&ssc=14&pln=39&pc=18#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) so that the 2 errors go away?

### This works

So given the following common stuff:

```
type Data = { id: number, name: string };
const data: Data[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Alice' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bob' }
]

type Header = { header: string };
```

Here's a variant that makes you supply a typesafe field name, and optionally a formatting function for the value of that field:

```
type Value1<Row> = {
  [Key in keyof Row]: {
    field: Key;
    format?: (value: Row[Key]) => string;
  };
}[keyof Row];

type Column1<Row> = Header & Value1<Row>;

const makeTable = <R>(r: R[], c: Column1<R>[]) => {}
makeTable(data, [
  { header: 'Id', field: 'id' },
  { header: 'Name', field: 'name', format: value => value.toUpperCase() },
])
```

Here's a variant that makes you only supply a formatting function, and instead of a value you get the row object:

```
type Value2<Row> = {
  format: (row: Row) => string;
};

type Column2<Row> = Header & Value2<Row>;

const makeTable = <R>(r: R[], c: Column2<R>[]) => {};
makeTable(data, [
  { header: 'Id', format: row => row.id.toString() },
  { header: 'Name', format: row => row.name.toUpperCase() },
])
```

### This does not...

The issue comes when I would like to *combine* these two, because for some columns the first variant makes sense, and for others the second one does.

I figured I could do it as follows, but Typescript is not happy...

```
type Column3<Row> = Header & (Value1<Row> | Value2<Row>); // <-- Non-working discriminated union?

const makeTable = <R>(r: R[], c: Column3<R>[]) => { };
makeTable(data, [
  { header: 'Id', field: 'id' },
  { header: 'Name', field: 'name', format: value => value.toUpperCase() },
  { header: 'Test', format: row => `${row.id} : ${row.name}` },
])
```

Apparently the type of `data` is now incorrect, and also that `row` in the third column for some reason is implicitly `any`, which it of course shouldn't be.

I can "fix" the type of `data` by being explicit about the generic `Row` type:

```
makeTable<Data>(data, [
  { header: 'Id', field: 'id' },
  { header: 'Name', field: 'name', format: value => value.toUpperCase() },
  { header: 'Test', format: row => `${row.id} : ${row.name}` },
])
```

But `row` is still implicitly `any`, and it really shouldn't be necessary to be explicit here, so something is definitely not right here... but... I don't understand what's going on here.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format is ambigeous as defined in both `Value1` and `Value2`
The compiler cannot tell `row`'s type between `Row[Key] //Value1` and `Row //Value2`
I suggest you to switch the `format` of both Value1 and Value2 :

```
type Value1<Row> = {
  [Key in keyof Row]: {
    field: Key;
    format_field?: (value: Row[Key]) => string;
  };
}[keyof Row];

type Value2<Row> = {
  format_row: (row: Row) => string;
};

(<R>(r: R[], c: Column3<R>[]) => {})<Data>(data, [
  { header: 'Id', field: 'id' },
  { header: 'Name', field: 'name', format_field: value => value.toUpperCase() },
  { header: 'Test', format_row: row => `${row.id} : ${row.name}` },
]) //No more ambigeous
```

Comment: Right, that actually seems to work great! I assumed Typescript would be able to keep them apart, and that I could use a `if( 'field' in column )` type guard to eventually separate them, but yeah. 

Answer (score 1):

So, let's chalk the wrong type on `data` up to generic default types (because `Row` is never defined as an actual type, I think Typescript defaults it to `string` at some point for purposes of type resolution (I may be wrong on this)).

The type of `row` being `any` in the `format` functions is due to Typescript [not inferring types for function arguments](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15114#issuecomment-293133377).  That thread has a lot of good discussion as to why.  In fact, at one point in the discussion, it is mentioned that

> there's nothing in TypeScript today that infers information about a variable from its usage.

For a short example of the complexities that can develop, what is the type of `row` in  `z.format`?

```js
type t = { format: (row: string) => string } | { format: (row: number) => number }
const z: t = {format: row => row }
```

Without additional annotation during usage:

```js
const z: t = {format: (row: number) => row}
```

The compiler cannot easily tell what shape `row` is supposed to be.  Unfortunately, this forces us to be explicit at times that we wouldn't expect to have to be.

To 'fix' the type for `Column3`, you just have to be a little more explicit in your usage:

```js
type Column3<Row> = Header & (Value1<Row> | Value2<Row>);
type R = Data
(<R>(r: R[], c: Column3<R>[]) => {})(data, [
  { header: 'Id', field: 'id' },
  { header: 'Name', field: 'name', format: value => value.toUpperCase() },
  { header: 'Test', format: (row: R) => `${row.id} : ${row.name}` },
])
```

Comment: Weird, but I guess that makes sense. What I don't understand is why `data` ends up being `string` though. Like, where does that come from?  If I specify the type of Row in the format function, then it suddenly gets the right type for `data` as well, but if I only use the `field` variant, then it forces me to explicitly specify the generic type to get it right. 

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too and I agree that it's weird. It may be a bug or an artifact of the type resolution hitting a base case? Idk